# Cannot save CHECKBOX field type in database - Joomla 2.5

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I have multiple `checkboxes` field in `Joomla 2.5` in my `.xml` file

```
<field name="player_number"
           type="text"
           label="Player number"
           description="Enter Player's number here"
           class="inputbox"
           size="30"
           required="true"
    />

    <field name="player_dob" type="calendar" default="" label="Select a date" description=""  required="true" format="%Y-%m-%d" />

    <field name="player_position" type="checkboxes">
        <option value="Left">Left</option>
        <option value="Right">Right</option>
        <option value="Middle">Middle</option>
    </field>
```

I have relevant data columns in database like `player_number`, `player_dob` and `player_position`.

I have Toolbars from where I can add a `NEW` record or `EDIT` the existing one.

I can successfully `ADD` `player_number` and `player_dob` and also the exiting value loads in the `EDIT` view.

Problem is that CHECKBOX value does not saves into database.

Even if I enter a value for `player_position` from `phpmyadmin` the relevant value does not show as CHECKED in the EDIT view form

Comment: How are you trying to get the value/state of the check box(es)?

Comment: You might also want to take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24620256/checkboxlist-in-joomla-component where it says that ckeckbox list field types do not store values by default.

Comment: @elk If I use RADIO buttons or the text fields or whatever, Joomla stores by itself .. If I use a single CHECKBOX ,, that works like others (saves and displayed as CHECKED in EDIT view) .,,, but not these CHECKBOXES (multiple)

Comment: Take a look at the unit test for checkboxes, it will show you the right way to set them up. The basic issue with checkboxes is what format do you want such as do you want csv, do you want array(), do you want associative array.  One of the easiest ways to solve is to wrap the field in a `<fields>` tag with the same name and that will save it as a json array I believe (that's just from memory).

Answer (score 1):

Annoyingly, this field type states in the documentation "It will create checkboxes for you, and submit their values in form of an array, but it will not store them in the database."

This means that you have to override the JTable store function if you want it to save.
[http://docs.joomla.org/API16:JTable/store](http://docs.joomla.org/API16%3aJTable/store)

The following code is the relevant code I last used when using Joomla 3 (2.5 should be similar). `demofield` is the name of my checkboxes and `edit` the name of the view where the checkboxes appear.   This override was saved under admin/tables/edit.php :

```
class TableEdit extends JTable {

    public function store($updateNulls = true)
    {

        JArrayHelper::toString($this->demofield);
        $this->demofield= implode(',', $this->demofield); 
        return parent::store($updateNulls);
    } 
}
```

Worth also noting that the list field type allows for multi-select, and will save in the database.  This may be a simpler solution.
http://docs.joomla.org/List_form_field_type

Comment: Actually as far as I know it will store them, but it's helpful to put them in json by using fields rather than field. I would not rely on the 1.6 API docs since there has been a ton of work on fields including a whole summer of code project last summer.

Comment: @Elin He's using 2.5, but do you have any link that gives an overview of what you mean by "using fields rather than field", as I'd like to know if there is a better way of doing this for new sites.

Comment: fields tags are used all over the core such as for storing the params or attribs data or the images or urls fields in content. Basically anything inside <fields> will be converted to json.

Comment: Thanks.  Tested it with a module and that works.  Shall have to see if it does in a component next time I'm setting one up.

Answer (score 0):

The set of checkboxes can be generated in your form with a single statement like this:

```
<?php echo $this->form->getInput('player_position'); ?>
```

This will generate the following HTML, which can be styled using CSS:

```
<fieldset id="jform_player_position" class="checkboxes">
    <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="jform_player_position0"
                    name="jform[player_position][]" value="Left" /><label for="jform_player_position0">Left</label></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="jform_player_position1"
                    name="jform[player_position][]" value="Right" /><label for="jform_player_position1">Right</label></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="jform_player_position2"
                    name="jform[player_position][]" value="Middle" /><label for="jform_player_position2">Middle</label></li>
     </ul>
```

If the user checks the first and third item and submits the form, the Joomla server will provide the following result:

```
print_r(JRequest::getVar('jform')['player_position']) =>
Array (
[0] => Left
[1] => Middle
)
```

Comment: Seems like I have seen this :P 

http://docs.joomla.org/Checkboxes_form_field_type